# Unable to find user data from a windows 10 (home) drive using Knoppix live USB

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, knoppix

Wife's laptop no longer boots after a failed windows 10 (home x64) update--bluescreen.  Windows also offers to try and recover (RE), which runs for awhile, then bluescreen's when it tries to boot back into windows.

Usually I'd take the drive out and connect it to another computer using a SATA to USB connector, however, based on it being a laptop, with a borked windows install, I'm trying to get the data off prior to attempting a clean reinstall/wipe as I believe the laptop to be in working order.  Confirmed, with some memory and disk checking tools, along with able to run Knoppix live distro. on the laptop.

I'm able to boot it with a Knoppix live USB thumb-drive.  However when I mount the NTFS filesystem holding C:, I only see Default, Public, and desktop.ini in what would have been C:\Users.

I've also tried a few searches using find in that filesystem (C:) for keywords of files/directories she would have had with out any luck.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction of where the data might be hiding?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Its likely the update is actually an upgrade, and as such user data is moved to c:\windows.old, the update performs, and then data is moved back as far as possible.

Comment: @davidPostill if I'm correct, none of the duplicates is the answer, therefor I think this question should remain open.

Comment: @LPChip Reopened, but the OP make no mention of being able to see `windows.old`

Comment: @DavidPostill yeah, its hidden in plain sight. If you don't expect it to be there and you read: the .old part, thinking that it is a left over from a blue moon ago, you disregard it as being the correct data.

Comment: @LPChip: The user is trying to find his missing folder under `C:\Users`, not `C:\Windows.old`.

Comment: @sleepyweasel: Are you sure you're mounting the right disk?

Comment: @harrymc yes, I'm mounting the right disk and partition.  There's only one drive in the laptop, and only one partition on it large enough to be the primary filesystem.  Other partitions are for boot, pqservice (Acer), and the windows RE.

Comment: Is it possible that your wife's user folder was relocated elsewhere, perhaps some time ago?

Answer (score 1):

Its likely the update is actually an upgrade, and as such user data is moved to c:\windows.old, the update performs, and then data is moved back as far as possible.

Therefor, you should be able to see the userfolders in C:\Windows.old. Backup that location, then perform a reinstall.

Comment: These are the files and folders inside what would have been C:\Windows.old:

WINDOWS
WINDOWS\System32
WINDOWS\System32\oobe
WINDOWS\System32\oobe\SetupPlatform
WINDOWS\System32\oobe\SetupPlatform\SetupPlatform.dll
WINDOWS\WinSxS
WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1790_none_7df2aec07ca10e81
WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1790_none_7df2aec07ca10e81\drvstore.dll
WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1790_none_7df2aec07ca10e81\msdelta.dll